# Are "You should rehearse the vocabularies from this lesson" and "You should go over the vocabularies from this lesson" similar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In the dictionaries

> [rehearse](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/rehearse)
>
> 2 [+ object] : to say or do (something) several times in order to
> practice
>
> lawyers rehearsing their closing arguments
>
> He rehearsed his dance moves in front of the mirror.

> [go over](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-over?q=go%20over): to study something carefully, especially by repeating it
>
> He went over the events of the day in his mind (= thought about them
> carefully).

It seems that both "**rehearse**" and "**go over**" both mean to repeat something several times to memorize something. But I am not sure these 2 words are equivalent in their meanings.

Are "**You should rehearse the vocabularies from this lesson**" and "**You should go over the vocabularies from this lesson**" similar?

**Which one is more common in everyday English?**

Comment: 'Review' has the same meaning as 'go over' and is very commonly used in the situation you're describing.  Unlike 'rehearse' (as @KateBunting pointed out), 'review' doesn't have the unwanted connotation of anticipating something.  So "You should **review** the vocabularies from this lesson" would have the same meaning as "You should **go over** the vocabularies from this lesson."  I don't know which is used more often ('review' or 'go over'), but 'review' has a slightly more formal tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the dictionary that you link to misleading, in that it treats the 'Definition 2' that you quote as being different from the 'rehearse a play' sense. You rehearse something that you are going to do, not something you have just learned. Oxford Languages (found by Googling 'rehearse definition') lists the sense *mentally prepare or recite (words one intends to say)* as a variant of the main definition, not a separate one.

So, no, you can't rehearse vocabulary you have just learned.

Comment: That is one of the problems of dictionaries. They sometimes do not give a clear nuance of words